# How to download a csv file in cms page

Tags: cms, download

I need to force a csv file's download from a cms page in Magento.
I've looking for many forums about it and I created a custom php code and insert it in blank empty cms page in Magento but the downloaded csv file contains html code with scripts and html tags before the file info.

So, how could I download the file without html code and only with the info I need?

Comment: I guess you need to set the right headers for this page and attach your csv. But I'm worried it won't come out right on a cms page, I'd advise you to use a link to a custom php, where you'd be able to correctly set the headers and echo your csv then die properly.

Comment: Hello. In cms page I only added this code {{block type="core/template" template="customphp/files.phtml"}} with empty design. And in "files.phtml" I put php code to force a file download. I don't understand if page has not design, why html code appears in csv file. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is the code in files.phtml:

Comment: $file = path-to-file header('Content-Type: application/download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="catalogo.csv"'); header("Content-Length: " . filesize("catalogo.csv"));

$fp = fopen($file, "r");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);

Comment: it's a cms page, no matter what you put in your phtml, header footer and such will still be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Just upload the CSV anywhere inside `media/` and create a link in the HTML page pointing to the CSV file (e.g. `http://www.yourstore.com/media/test.csv`). The browser will allow you to open the file in an office application or download the file.